# Profiling bandwidth and speed of different WCF bindings

Tags: wcf, performance, wcf-binding

I'm interested in knowing the different bandwidth and performance characteristics of the different WCF bindings (basicHttp, WSHttp, nettcp, etc.).  Aside from writing a service and exposing the different endpoint bindings that we can call to exercise, how could I measure these metrics?

In particular, I need to know how bandwidth and performance scales as number of messages go up in number.

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that looking at bindings alone will answer that question as are there are other factors like concurrency, instancing and throttling that weigh heavily on how a given service will perform. That being said, here's a great post that tried to take a look at certain performance aspects of the various bindings:

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200207095351/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/BVeldhoen/archive/2008/01/26/wcf-latency-test-harness.aspx)